# Can't refer to files in different directory

Tags: php, html

I'm having trouble making the files to be found by each others. Let's say I have the Login_Success.php, which has the logout button

```
<form name="lgt" action="Logout.php" method="post">
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td><?php
if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['username']."";
}
?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="lgout" value="Logout"></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I put this file into *root/action* directory; I also place another file named Logout in the same directory.  This is my Logout.php file (I put my index.php in *root* directory)

```
<?php session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:/index.php");
?>
```

Now I'm facing with a problem that when I login successfully, I can easily logout from Login_Success and go back to the index.php for another login session.  But when I stand there, I go back to the index.php (NOT logout yet, just type index.php to the navigation bar) and I can't logout anymore.  It says:

> Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the
>   referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author
>   of that page about the error.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404
>
> localhost Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15

I know the problem is that my Logout.php can't be found, just because the index.php and the Logout.php are not in the same directory, unlike these 2.

The index I wrote very simple for I am new to PHP language, I just want the User Information to be replaced the login form when I successfully login.  So I wrote like this

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<?php 
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
include "pc/LoginForm.php";
}
else
{
include "pc/ProfileInfo.php";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm stuck with this for a couple of days. Now I want to logout at index.php either. Hope to hear from you support very soon.

Sincerely,

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded inside the page where you have the form?

Comment: Hi Fred, I also wrote the LoginForm.php and I didn't use session_start() there. 
P/S: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: It's required to be inside all files using sessions. Add it and try again. `<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){...}`

Comment: You meant my first block? It has the session_start() already.  I just didn't copy all those lines.

Comment: Ok. Well, it's hard to say then. Have you not assigned a session variable to the login name?

Comment: You're welcome, but what do you mean by "I made it"? You've got success?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing the creation of a $_SESSION variable for the username, simply checking if it exists.

Generally log in scripts are a 3-part affair.

1. Display log in form for user to fill
2. Link to login-checker.php(you should have another file that verifies username, password,
     permission,etc) that compares user input from the form to the user info in the database
         -> this is where you set your VERIFIED input as your $_SESSION variables
3. Logout.php file to kill the session when you're done (don't change anything there, that's right!)

Seems to me like you should revisit steps one and two.